# Repeating authorization Window

Tags: iphone, facebook, authorization

I'm using Xcode 4.3.1

In my app I try to use Facebook SSO.My requirement is at the first time the app should ask for the authorization after that it should check whether the app is authorized by the user and should move to the next process(even after the task in the device is cancelled).I don't that authorization window to repeat again and again.

in Appdelegate:

```
facebook=[[Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:appid andDelegate:first];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"%@Defaults:",[defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]);
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
    {
       facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        accessToken=facebook.accessToken;
       facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        date=facebook.expirationDate;
    }
In my view Controller:



    -(IBAction)LoginClick:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults1 setObject:xapp.facebook.accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults1 setObject:xapp.facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults1 synchronize];
    if (![xapp.facebook isSessionValid]) 
    {
         permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"read_stream",@"publish_stream", nil];
        [xapp.facebook authorize:permissions];
    }
    else if([xapp.facebook isSessionValid])
    { 
        NSLog(@"Hiii");
        permissions=nil;
        [xapp.facebook authorize: nil];
    }
}
```

How can I make the authorization window to not appear after the app is authorized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you are asking for permissions each time you run your app in your AppDelegate. To prevent this, you have to make a separate method for permission that will be granted only if the login button is pressed and checked if the app is permitted or not. Try this in your AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOURAPPID" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
    {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Above your fbDidLogIn method in your AppDelegate add this method, you have to add the FBUser protocol to your AppDelegate:

```
-(void)fbLogin:(id<FBUser>)_listener
{
    listener = _listener;
    if(![facebook isSessionValid])
    {
        NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 @"publish_stream",
                                 @"read_stream",
                                 nil] retain];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
    }
    else
    {
        [listener facebookDidLogin];
    }
}
```

And in your ViewController modify your login method like this:

```
-(IBAction)LoginClick:(id)sender
{
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate fbLogin:self];
}
```

The FBUser.h is a custom header file that defines the protocol method -(void)fbDidLogIn. This is just to make sure that, the app does not ask login permission each it time launches.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol FBUser <NSObject>

-(void)facebookDidLogin;

@end
```

By this, the login method is only called when the app needs to login to Facebook and do something.
Hope this helps you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for ur code...But I'm getting an error at [listener facebookDidLogin]; "No known instance method for selector 'fbDidLogin'"

Comment: This is to prevent asking permission every time you login. Check the updated answer.

Comment: create a custom header file named FBUser.h according to my updated answer.